# Install ImageMagick over active SSH Session

Tags: software-installation, manjaro, imagemagick

How could you install ImageMagick over SSH session? I have been using

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

and then:

```
tar xfvz ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

to unpack the archive, but once I reach that step, it either freezes up or takes a long time to respond to commands.  Can I have a hand, please?
The server I ssh'd to is running Manjaro Linux.

Comment: SSH is pretty un-related to installing software. What system are you installing it on?

Comment: On Manjaro Linux

Comment: You would install it exactly the same way as you would do in any other shell session. Could you please clarify what issue you are having? (by editing you question, not by writing comments!)

Comment: How about just `tar -xf ImageMagick.tar.gz` ?  The filename must follow the `-f` flag, and the `-z` and `-v` options aren't necessary.

Comment: @user4556274 No. When using "bundled option" with `tar`, the filename does _not_ need to follow `f` immediately. When using the standard, "dashed", options, then the filename _has_ to follow `-f` immediately. What you are showing should make no difference, assuming they are using GNU `tar` (which enables `-z` automatically).

Comment: How much RAM? free disk?

Comment: 3945 mebibytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind!  I managed to enable root login over SSH by editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and then just used `pacman -S imagemagick` to install, but thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Now you have a slightly more vulnerable system. It would have been better to SSH in as an ordinary user and then use `sudo pacman ...` on the remote machine.

Comment: I cannot use the `sudo` command on the remote machine, if I could this question wouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: Then `su -` first to get a root shell, install, and log out. Enabling root logins on the server should not be necessary.  By the way, how did you log in to edit the `sshd_config` file if root logins were disabled and you couldn't use `sudo`?

Comment: Ahh... The file I edited was on my side of the server.  But why?  As I stated in my answer, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a terminal [screen session](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). A screen session is a special type of terminal session that won't die if your network connection dies, your local computer is restarted, etc. You can then simply open up the screen session again when your network permits, and continue where you left off.

## Installation

Installing on Arch:

```
pacman -S screen
```

Ubuntu:

```
apt install screen
```

CentOS:

```
yum install screen
```

## Usage

SSH into your remote machine, and run `screen`. You are now in a screen session.

Do whatever you need, example:

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

If your connection to the server dies, simply SSH in again and run:

```
screen -x
```

Notice the `-x` flag. Your terminal session is now resumed like nothing was ever closed. Type exit to close it when done.

Note that screen sessions allow for multiple highly managed instances and has tons of functionality. They are out of scope here though, so wont be covered.